# Can`t call console.log() from event listener

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-emulator

I'm performing an app for tizen, but it has a lot of pure JS code and I faced with strange problem. I have such listener of event:

```
messagesChangeListener: function () {
    var self = this, config,
messageChangeCallback = {
    messagesupdated: function (updateMessages) {
        //console.log('Message updated');
    },
    messagesadded: function (addedMessage) {
        //console.log('Message added: ');
        self.outputlog(addedMessage);
    },
    messagesremoved: function (removedMessages) {
        //console.log('Message removed');
    }
};  this.smsService.messageStorage.addMessagesChangeListener(messageChangeCallback);
    },

outputlog: function(messages) {
    console.log("Messages changed");
},
```

As you see I have event handlers, where commented calls of console log, but I get in this case error 'Cannot call method 'log' of undefined', I have to add new method outputlog for tests purpose. It works, but once Tizen emulator reloaded - it also stops working.

So:

1. Why I cann't call console.log directly from event handlers? I suppose it is a problem of visibility and a problem of pure JS. Am I right?
2. May be somebody know why method outputlog stops working after reloading of emulator? Here I suppose some specific problem of Tizen app and emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you put a semicolon and extra curly here:

```
    messagesremoved: function (removedMessages) {
        //console.log('Message removed');
    }
};  this.smsService.messageStorage.addMessagesChangeListener(messageChangeCallback);
    },
```

Comment: Semicolon and curly are closing definition of var messageChangeCallback.

Answer (score 0):

Do you look at the "console" tab in the Chrome console, or only the log in the SDK?
Check if both exhibit the same behaviour, possibly it's a communication issue in the SDK.

Comment: Look like in both the same way.

Comment: This answer totally saved me even though it turned out to be almost completely unrelated. I've been trying to figure out for about a half an hour why my event.preventDefault() is working but the console.log isn't, and it turned out I was looking at the console for a different window.